Calculating SHAP values using lightgbm 'regression sqrt' objective
It appears that there is an issue when using the built-in objective function of regression sqrt in lightgbm. The issue isn't with the actual model training, that seems to work fine, but when calculating the SHAP values with the model using
shap_values_df = pd.DataFrame(shap_values, columns=best_model.feature_name())
the values don't make any sense anymore. Seems like maybe the SHAP values are the square roots or something, but even then the math doesn't work out.
Does anyone have an explanation for this? Am I doing something wrong?
I tried to display a waterfall chart to go from E(x) to the prediction, but the magnitude of all the SHAP values are much too small to account for the actual magnitude difference.

It decomposes the square-root of the predictions.
